# MySQL replace numbers after hyphen

Tags: mysql

I have a large table with ZIP codes but they are in long format like : 06608-1405

What I require is to REMOVE the hyphen and the numbers after the hyphen. I have using MYSQL REPLACE before but not sure how if you can use Wildcards.

Cheers for you time.

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(ZIP, '-', 1);
```

Edit:

To update the table:

```
Update <table-name> set ZIP = SUBSTRING_INDEX(ZIP, '-', 1);
```

Comment: This works perfect but they are still in the db do you know how to remove the hyphen and numbers after it?

Comment: Cheers, codaddict!  Works a charm.  Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers before the hypen are all the same length (5), you can do `SUBSTRING(zip, 0, 5)`

Or even `SUBSTRING(zip, 0, LOCATE('-', zip))`

Or `LEFT(zip, LOCATE('-', zip))` if you wanna follow the other suggestion that was made.

Answer (score 0):

use a combination of the left() the instr() functions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

i.e.

```
select left('12345-6789', instr('12345-6789', '-') - 1)
```

returns

```
12345
```

(could/should be refined to only carry out left() operation if instr() returns a non-zero value).

**EDIT**: to remove the hyphen etc. use:

```
update my_table
set my_col = left(my_col, instr(my_col, '-') - 1)
```

Comment: Cheers for this but I really need to remove the hyphen and numbers after it.

Answer (score 0):

If they're all ZIP codes (i.e., 5 digits, hyphen, 4 digits), you can just use:

```
mysql> SELECT LEFT(table.zip_code, 5); // (06608-1405 -> 06608)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left